# Which app is giving this pop-up? "To allow the app to access your private key, enter the password"

Tags: windows-10, certificate

I'm getting the following unexpected pop-up on a regular basis. I have no idea which program is producing it, and entering my usual passwords doesn't work.

[image]

Using Process Explorer, I've determined that the window itself is part of the Windows component CredentialUIBroker.exe, but that still doesn't tell me which program requested it.

Is there an event log, or diagnostic tool I can use to figure out where these pop-ups are coming from?

Comment: Check with Process Monitor (free MS SysInternals tool), do a quick capture, filter to show only the process you care about (CredentialUIBroker), and if you choose Tool and then Process Tree, you should be able to see what the parent process/service is.

Comment: Running into the same problem and there's no meaningful parent process for `CredentialUIBroker.exe` in my case, only `svchost.exe`. No idea how MS could find `the app` to be of any help... :-/ The whole point is currently that I don't know which action triggers that dialog for what reason.

Comment: It may be useful for others with this problem to know that the pop up likely occurs because the private key of a certificate is being read and that when that certificate was imported the option "Enable strong private key protection" was set. This option says "You will be prompted every time the private key is used by an application if you enable this option". If you're seeing this and recently added a cert, go to the Certificates console, delete the cert and reimport it without the "Enable strong private key protection" option set and you will no longer be prompted.

Comment: @MarkWragg You are right. This will disable the password prompt. But this would be like removing the door to a home because... doorbells are annoying. Keeping your private key private and protected might be a good idea. Depending on what the certificate is for and if exporting is allowed... This could give a hacker with malicious intent access to your bank account if this key is for online banking. Or to sign things on your behalf - AFAIK a digital signature is considered equal to a physical signature by law. Disappointing that MS made such a vague dialogue for something so important.

Comment: @ThorstenSchöning I noticed that in ProcessExplorer you can find the specific instance of svchost.exe by PID, and then double-click on it to get... a list of services it is hosting. In my case, it listed 5 services, but only PlugPlay and SystemsEventsBroker are running. The last one is most likely, more specifically the "Task Scheduler"... Then if we open the Task Scheduler, we can get a list of running tasks... And you can kill tasks one by one and close the password prompt to figure out which one it is... I stopped getting the prompt after a Cache related task was killed. Weird. Reboot time.